# MultiThreading to count the number of files inside folder using Python

Tags: python, multithreading

So , i have code which should fetch count of file and related details from a folder . So a folder will contain number of subfolders , but since the root folder contains many subfolders and files inside that it takes lot of time to fetch details . So i wanted to implement MultiThreading concept with this .  so that a thread will be assigned to each folder to find the count of files , since am new to this multithreading concepts especially with Python , i don know how to start or where to start . Can anyone help me on this .

So below is my code :

```
import os
import time
import glob
import stat

root =roots = 'C:/Users/Logs_of_Hell'
count_of_file = 0

import pathlib
noOfFiles = local_time_of_oldest = local_time_of_newest= 0
subdir=""
N = 0

def Count_files_in_subd():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(roots):
        #Here is the place i have to implement MultiThreading ,
        # when it gets a new directory a new thread to be assigned to it which will count the files in that particular directory , similarly a 
        #unique thread is assigned to each dir and after assigning the thread , the thread should perform counting and finding oldest_file etc parallely . so that time will be  reduced
        taggedrootdir = pathlib.Path(root)
        # print(root)
        oldest_file = (
            min([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getmtime))
        newest_file = (
            max([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getmtime))

        folder = {}
        folder['FolderPath'] = root
        folder['count'] = len(files)
        folder['Old'] = oldest_file
        folder['New'] = newest_file

        print(folder)

Count_files_in_subd()
```

Can anyone guide me or help me with this

Comment: On an I/O heavy task like directory listing multi-threading is not going increase speed very much. Depending on the drive type it can even reduce the overall speed because the many parallel drive accesses.

Comment: So , what do u think is the best way to speed up this activity @KlausD.

Comment: His point was you will be limited by the disk I/O speed.  It is the bottleneck.  You have a fixed amount of I/O to do, no matter how many threads there are.  There is likely no way to speed it up.

Comment: The bottleneck is the I/O. Most factors influencing the I/O speed are in layers below Python code (OS, drive…). The main influence an application can have is how it requests data from the OS. The longer the access time of the drive is, the more important it becomes to *not* send different requests at the same time. Multi-threading would do exactly that undesired parallel access.

Comment: So there is no use of me trying anything to speed up

Comment: How many times is folder printed?